# Inline asm in GCC, specifying offset by expression

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, inline-assembly

Not exactly sure how to title this, but
I want to emulate this code:

```
asm("movl %%fs:0x30, %0" : "=r" (peb) : : );
```

but I want to specify the offset variably in C

trying:

```
    int mee = 48;
asm("movl %%fs:%1, %0"

     : "=r" (peb)
     : "r" (mee)
     :
     );
```

Error is `bad memory operand '%eax'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what you have written, the compiler translates the first operand to `%fs:%eax` because it chooses `%eax` to be the register holding the value of `mee`.  The addressing mode I think you're trying to use is *base*:*offset* and the offset must be a *value* rather than a register.  This is the reason for the error "bad memory operand".  It worked in the `%fs:0x30` case because `0x30` is an immediate value.

To use the register `%eax` as an offset, try a dereference of it `%%fs:(%1)` to get the value *in the register*:

```
       int mee = 48;
       asm("movl %%fs:(%1), %0" : "=r" (peb) : "r" (mee) :);
```

See also [this guide](http://wiki.osdev.org/Inline_Assembly/Examples), which contains some possibly useful examples of memory access (and more) in inline assembly.